# Variable not being initialized, Void methods cannot return a value, cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, string, variables, input

I'm trying to get user input to find out the name of the file the user wants to open, however in my setName() method although i think it should be, the variable FileName is not being initialized.
I might have another problem with the getName() method too but i'm not sure what it is.
Can i get some help please?!

```
public void setName(){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String FileName;
    boolean done = false;

    do{#Until the user enters a proper input it should continue to ask for input
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the input file!");
        if(input.hasNextLine()){
            FileName = input.next();
            done = true;

        }else{
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid name");
        }


    }while(!done);

    return FileName // not being initialized and "Void methods cannot return a value"

}
public String getName(){
    return FileName; //The IDE says "FileName cannot be resolved to a variable"
```

Comment: declare `FileName` globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code makes no sense. Your trying to return a String in a void where you want to set something. So there is no reason to write `return FileName;` for whatever reason there(therefor you have your getName method). 2nd thing you need to initialize a `private String FileName` before your both Methods. Then in your method `setName()` after you said `FileName = input.next();` you need to say `this.FileName = FileName;` so you actually have a variable that you can use. Heres the code and how i would do it:

```
private String FileName;

public void setName(){

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String FileName;

do{#Until the user enters a proper input it should continue to ask for input
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the input file!");
    if(input.hasNextLine()){
        FileName = input.next();
        this.FileName = FileName

    }else{
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid name");
    }

public String getName(){
    return FileName;#The IDE says it can't resolve symbol FileName
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should not start varible name with capital letter (it works fine but it is bed convention) second your FileName only lives inside of setName() method getName() does not know about its existence it is called variable scope here you can read about it http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/scope-and-lifetime-of-variables. Any way you probably wanted some thing like this

```
public class YourClassName {

String fileName;
public String setName(){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean done = false;

    do{
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the input file!");
        if(input.hasNextLine()){
            fileName = input.next();
            done = true;

        }else{
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid name");
        }


    }while(!done);

    return fileName;
}
public String getName() {
    return fileName;
}
```

}

Notice how fileName is declared outside of any method this kind of virable is called field.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `FileName` must starts from a lowercase letter - `fileName`. In your code this variable is local, but if you want to use `getName()` method, it must be a field. And your `setName()` method must return a `String`. About this:

> FileName is not being initialized.

The assignment of a variable `FileName` is in the condition - `if(input.hasNextLine())`. And if the condition is not satisfied, variable not initialized. You need to initialize the variable when you declare or in the `else` block.

All code:

```
public class ClassName {
    String fileName;

    public String setName() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;

        do { // until the user enters a proper input it should continue to ask for input
            System.out.println("Please enter the name of the input file!");
            if (input.hasNextLine()) {
                fileName = input.next();
                done = true;
            } else {
                fileName = "Default";
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid name");
            }
        } while (!done);

        return fileName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return fileName;
    }
}
```